# How to use variables in VBScript StartConnection method

Tags: vbscript, hta

I tried to develop a HTA application with VBScript as scripting language. Below is the code:

```
Sub SysStart()
  Dim Mgr
  Dim autECLPSObj
  Dim autECLConnList
  Set Mgr = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnMgr")
  Set Obj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLOIA")
  Obj.SetConnectionByName (dsession)
  If Obj.Started = "False" Then
    MsgBox(dtext)
    MsgBox(dsession)
    Mgr.StartConnection("profile=dtext connname=dsession WINSTATE=MAX")
  Else
    Mgr.StopConnection dsession, "saveprofile=no"
    Mgr.StartConnection("profile= dtext connname=dsession WINSTATE=MAX")
  End If
End Sub
```

The variables dsession,dtext are already defined in another function in the same program.
Here `dsession` is the session name and `dtext` is the profile name. `StartConnection` and `StopConnection` are methods of `PCOMM.autECLConnMgr` used to establish connection with IBM PCOMM.

For Personal Communications, the configuration string has the following format:

```
PROFILE=[']['] [CONNNAME=] [WINSTATE=]
```

Same code Without variables:

```
Dim Mgr
Dim autECLPSObj
Dim autECLConnList
Set Mgr = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnMgr")
Set Obj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLOIA")
Obj.SetConnectionByName ("B")
If Obj.Started = "False" Then
  Mgr.StartConnection("profile=test1.WS connname=B WINSTATE=MAX")
Else
  Mgr.StopConnection "B", "saveprofile=no"
  Mgr.StartConnection("profile=test1.WS connname=B WINSTATE=MAX")
End If
```

When I tried running the code without variables its working but when I tried with variable following error arises:

[image: Error]

> ECL37240: Invalid WS profile name. Invalid data

My question is: can we use variables in the `StartConnection` method? If yes then how?

Note: I have checked the values of variables and all are correct.

Comment: Hi Ansgar..It is not a duplicate question.Its about IBM PCOMM connection object and how to pass variable in startConnection Method to connect HTA application to IBM PCOMM.
Please do reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your problem, you need to pass the variable values to startManager method. You need to use the variables like the below

```
If Obj.Started = "False" Then
  Msgbox(dtext)
  Msgbox(dsession)
  Mgr.StartConnection("profile=" & dtext & " connname=" & dsession &"  WINSTATE=MAX")    
End if
```

'This is an untested code. Also, I am not HTA expert.'

Comment: Hi Mithilesh..Thanks a lot...It works :) :)

Comment: Hi @Mithilesh Indurkar,

Your method works but it didn't work for below code:
 
Obj.SetConnectionByName (dsession)

Its takes session as D as in dsession not  A provided by user.Is there any way to pass this variable.

Many thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Kamakshya Please do remember to accept the answer(by clicking the tick mark next to the answer) which works for you, as a token of appreciation. Also, for your above issue, I think you need to ask another question

Comment: If i use (& dsession &), i am getting Syntax Error.And if i use ("& dsession &") i am getting AUTECL: Invalid input parameter passed.
Thank you :)

Comment: & (ampersand) sign is used to join 2 strings. e.g. "Hello" & "World".... you do not need to use the dsession variable in such way.... Obj.SetConnectionByName(dsession) should work

Comment: Yes working!! Thanks a lot :) Really appreciate your help..much needed :)

Comment: I have used the steps that you mentioned above and its working in my pc but when i moved it to another pc its not working..same error.Can you help me on this.Do i need ask another question? please reply..thanks

Comment: Yes please, ask a new one